# Gparted crashed during resize. Can I recover data?

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted, partition-recovery

I was using Gparted on a live Disk to resize and it crashed midway. Now I'm booting to see this:

```
BusyBox v1.38.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-6ubuntu2) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Is there any way I can recover my data ?

I can Boot into Windows, I was resizing my Pop os partition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can most likely recover your data using Testdisk - this free software can scan and recover partitions and has saved me from similar issues to yours before.

Depending on what happened during the resize, you may, of-course, also be able to simply USB Boot and read the data.

I do note that best practice would be to do a bitcopy of the drive before running testdisk on it, just in case it makes things worse.  I've never lost data as a result of using testdisk, but block level operations of this type are considered fairly high risk.

Comment: I have no idea how to use it, can you recommend a guide ?

Comment: Have you Googled for it?  Here is a starting point from the authors - https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: Maybe this is of use to you - https://lmgtfy.app/?q=testdisk+partition+table+type+